# Load Unity game scene from AssetBundle

Tags: dynamic, unity-game-engine, scene, assetbundle

I try to load Unity scene from AssetBundle with following code:

```
using (WWW www = WWW.LoadFromCacheOrDownload("http://127.0.0.1:8080/unity/test-scene", 1))
{
    yield return www;
    if (www.error != null)
    {
        Debug.Log("Load Error " + www.error);
    }

    AssetBundle bundle = www.assetBundle;
    Object[] loadObjectList = bundle.LoadAllAssets();

    foreach(Object tempObj in loadObjectList)
    {
        Debug.Log("Object = " + tempObj);
    }
}
```

For scene base bundles I always got 0 elements for `loadObjectList` array.

If I call `bundle.GetAllScenePaths()` function I got scene path(s), but if I try to load those scene(s) using `SceneManager.LoadScene()` function I got following error message:

"*(-1) Scene couldn't be loaded because it has not been added to the build settings or the AssetBundle has not been loaded*".

Did someone know how to load scene from AssetBundle or is this is limitation of Unity?

Answer (score 2):

Finally I figure-out how to do this: If I specify path and file extension to `LoadScene()` function it may get fail.

For example:

`SceneManager.LoadScene("Assets/demosc1.unity");` is not working and produced above error. This needs to be modify as `SceneManager.LoadScene("demosc1");`.